# Ограничение по времени цикла while

Tags: python, время, while

Мне нужно, чтобы цикл `while` в данном коде завершался после 2 секунд и выводил число, которое он насчитает за эти 2 секунды.

```
i = 1
while i < 10000000:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, топорный вариант, но влияние других команд на время исполнения минимально. На моей машине досчитывает до 30М+ за 2 сек. Основа - запуск функции в отдельном потоке через `threading`, пауза 2 секунды и завершение запущенной функции с помощью глобальной переменной. Счетчик - тоже глобальная переменная.
Ограничение `<10_000_000` убрал, `print()` в цикле тоже убрал.

```
import threading, time


def calculate():
    global i, run
    while run:
        i += 1


i, run = 0, True
threading.Thread(target=calculate).start()
time.sleep(2)
run = False
print(f'{i:,}')
```

```
30,300,237
```

ЗЫ. Можно запускать соревнование - кто больше насчитает за 2 секунды :)

Comment: Если убрать `print` из цикла и поменять на `while True` мой вариант в `Google Colab` больше успевает насчитать, чем ваш ))  И это логично - сигналы работают быстрее, чем создание дополнительного треда.

Comment: @CrazyElf протестил свой код в колабе. Очень волатильный результат при нескольких запусках - различается кратно. Очевидно, на каждый запуск свой объем вычислительных ресурсов выделяется. Если запускать коды по очереди, сравнимости не будет. Сравнивали оба кода в одном запуске?

Comment: Ну я просто по нескольку раз запускал две разных ячейки по очереди, вроде результаты стабильные были более-менее. Так то понятно, что много от чего может зависеть.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так (в лоб):

```
import time              
st_t=time.time()  #время старта
fin_t=st_t+2    #время окончания цикла
i=1
while time.time()<fin_t:    #пока время меньше fin_t
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

Мы учитываем, что время затрат на импортирование модуля `time` и вычисления
`~ 0`.

---

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
...
314
315
316
```

---

**UPD: уберите `print` из тела цикла, разница в выводе огромна! Без него выводит `~3699632`, с ним `~300`:**

```
import time              
st_t=time.time()  #время старта
fin_t=st_t+2    #время окончания цикла
i=1
while time.time()<fin_t:    #пока время меньше fin_t
    i+=1
print(i)
```

Вывод:

```
3699632
```

Comment: Если оставить `print` в цикле, то основное время потратится именно на `print`. Мне кажется нужно на после цикла `print` перенести, если я правильно понял задачу.

Comment: Так оно выдаёт разные числа

Comment: @skrizyoffical так и в твоём коде выдаёт все числа по порядку

Comment: @CrazyElf на телефоне разница с принт в цикле и без примерно 45 раз.

Comment: @CrazyElf согласен, но это было в коде автора... Не имею права его исправлять:) Вдруг ему так нужно

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант через декоратор таймаута:

```py
# !pip install timeout-decorator

import timeout_decorator

i = 1

@timeout_decorator.timeout(2, timeout_exception=TimeoutError)
def mytest():
    global i
    while i < 10000000:
        print(i)
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:   
        mytest()
    except TimeoutError:
        print('Вышел таймаут')
```

Я бы вынес `print` из цикла, ибо вывод на экран - это самое тормозное действие. Но мало ли зачем вам это надо, из комментариев непонятно.